# Can someone verify this calculus problem solution for me?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

From the origin point **O**, a particle moves with velocity **4m/min**, in the direction $30$ degrees north-east. After one minute, another particle **B** moves from **O** on the line **$x + \sqrt3y = 0$**, with velocity **6m/min**, in the direction (BOA), which is an acute angle. Evaluate the rate of change of the distance between **A** and **B** after 2 mins, from moving the particle **B**.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I think X= 12 because 
X=x○ + dx/dt ×t 
= 0+4×(2+1) = 4×3 =12 
because it says after moving B and B moves after A with 1 min . 
then Y = y○ + dy/dt ×t 
= 0+6×2 = 12 
So dS/ dt = 5(root)3
am I right ???